# Python Web scraping with user input?

Tags: python, web-scraping

This is my first time trying web scraping. im trying to find gas prices by state.  the first code i did which worked was

```
url = "https://www.gasbuddy.com/usa/la"

    page = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    title = soup.find(id= "Nevada").get_text()
    price = soup.find("div", class_="col-sm-2 col-xs-3 text-right").get_text()
    print(price)
    print(title)
```

Now I want to make it so the user can input the state.  In the first program I just selected one state and wrote it as such

```
title = soup.find(id= "Nevada").get_text()
```

how would i make it so this would work

```
State = input("Input Your State ")
title = soup.find(id= State ).get_text()
```

Comment: Yes, this. What's the problem with this way of asking for `input`?

Answer (score 0):

The website is protected by cloudflare. This why you can't scrape it using normal requests. You can use cloudscraper module for scraping it.
install it: `pip install cloudscraper`

code:

```
import cloudscraper
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

url = "https://www.gasbuddy.com/usa/la"

page = scraper.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

state = input("Input Your State ").strip()
title = soup.find(id= state ).get_text()

price = soup.find("div", class_="col-sm-2 col-xs-3 text-right").get_text()
print(price)
print(title)
```